# Log files are getting created when debbuging but while launching through the .app, log files are not created?

Tags: objective-c

Scenario: Im elstablishing a connection with an http server using libcurl and downlading a files.(by writing the response from the server into the file).

When im debugging my code im able to find the file saved in the specified path, and im also creating some log files which im able to find while debugging.

But, Once im creating the Releaes build and launching the application by invoking the .app file created im not able to find the downloaded files and the log files.

I dont understand the problem..........

sounds strange but i dont know what i have missed?

Please if somebody came across such a situtation pleaes get back to me soon....
Thank You Pradeep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the first time im working on MAC and was workin on windows till now..
While creating the log files im not giving the full application path...rather i was just giving the file name.....but once i gave the application path for creating the log files it was working for me..........

bad question....but might be helpfull to someone......